# The best way to mock shared services in Jest

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I'm using Jest for my unit tests. In my app, there're some shared services that are widely used in my components. Currently, I have to repeatedly mock all services in each test suite.

```
jest.mock('service1');
jest.mock('service2');
jest.mock('service3');

describe('Test suite A') {...}
```

What's the cleanest way to mock all these services for each test suite? Something like mocking them in jest config before tests run or mocking them all in a global class and import that class in each test suite...